# R aggregate function with two values

Tags: r, aggregate

Let's say I have a function that takes two vectors:

```
someFunction <- function(x,y){
  return(mean(x+y));
}
```

And say I have some data

```
toy <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2), b=rnorm(10), c=rnorm(10))
```

What I want to do is return the result of the function `someFunction` for each value of `toy$a`, i.e. I want to acchieve the same result as the code

```
toy$d <- toy$b + toy$c
result <- aggregate(toy$d, list(toy$a), mean)
```

However, in real life, the function someFunction is **way** more complicated and it **needs** two inputs, so the workaround in this toy example is not possible. So, what I want to do is:

- Group the data set according to one column.
- For each value in the column (in the toy example, that's 1 and 2), take **two** vectors `v1`, `v2`, and return `someFunction(v1,v2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout `dplyr` package, specifically `group_by` and `summarize` functions.
Assuming that you want to compute `someFunction(b, c)` for each value of `a`, the syntax would look like

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(a) %>% summarize(someFunction(b, c))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
toy <- data.table(toy)
toy[, list(New_col = someFunction(b, c)), by = 'a']
```